# Why is a true value rendered as "value"?

Tags: pug

I have:

```
input(type="hidden" name="x" value=pax?pax.C1a:undefined)
```

When `pax` as passed to `response.render` is `{ C1a: true }` the output is rendered as:

```
<input type="hidden" name="x" value="value" />
```

Shouldn't it be "true"?

When `pax.C1a` is false, it is rendered as:

```
<input type="hidden" name="x" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [HTML5 spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes):

> A number of attributes are **boolean attributes**. The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.
>
> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.
>
> ***Note:** The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes.*

`<input type="hidden" name="x" value="value" />` is the second case mentioned in the second paragraph I quoted; the first case would be `<input type="hidden" name="x" value />`, both representing the true boolean. The note explicitly says what you think should be happening (`value="true"`) should *not* be happening.

If you really want `value="true"`, you have to treat it as a text attribute, and render with `{ C1a: "true" }`.

Comment: Thanks but it is `type="hidden"` or `type="text"` and the attribute is `value` which is not boolean. Shouldn't this be a pug issue rather than Html?

Comment: If anything, it is a pug _user_ issue. Pug doesn't care what other attributes say. If you specify a boolean attribute, it renders a boolean attribute, by the rules for a boolean attribute. If you want to render a text attribute but giving pug a boolean value, PEBKAC :)

Comment: By "attribute" are you referring to a property of the Javascript object passed to render, or the attribute in the Html markup?

Comment: The latter, but they are parallel. If you give pug a boolean value, it will render a boolean attribute, per quoted rules. If you give pug a string value, it will render a generic text attribute with that precise value. Pug doesn't know HTML5 tag-specific definitions that it could decide for itself whether `input[value]` is boolean or not, it just goes by the type of the value you pass it.